# Existe [FromUri] equivalente em Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc

Em ASPNET MVC, temos o seguinte trecho de código que envia informações por meio da queryString e são recebidas em um endpoint o qual possui um parametro do tipo DTORequest e atraves do atributo [FromUri] é feito o auto-binding para as propriedades

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("search")]
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Search([FromUri] DTORequest request)
        {
            var result= _MyService.Search(request);
            return base.CreateSimpleResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
```

Existe algo equivalente em Java com Spring MVC para o mesmo proposito ?

```
        @GetMapping("search")
        public ResponseEntity<?> Search(@FromUri DTORequest request)
        {
            var result= _MyService.Search(request);
            return base.CreateSimpleResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de nada equivalente, o Spring faz isso sozinho. Seu objeto precisa ter um construtor público com os parâmetros ou um construtor público vazio e setters;

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/teste")
    public ResponseEntity<String> teste(ObjetoTeste params) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(params.toString()); 
    }
    
    @Data // construtor/getter/setters/toString
    class ObjetoTeste {
        private Integer i;
        private String s;
    }
}

// request = /teste?i=10&s=texto
// saída = Controller.ObjetoTeste(i=10, s=texto)
```

Comment: Top !! valeu @Mateus...deu certo brother